# How can I number adjacent value groups in pandas?

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to number distinct partitions of adjacent values.
The closest that I can currently get is the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'c'], columns=['letter'])

df['partition'] = df.groupby('letter').ngroup()
```

This is what I'm currently getting:

```
  letter  partition
0      a          0
1      a          0
2      b          1
3      b          1
4      a          0
5      c          2
```

This is my desired output:

```
  letter  partition
0      a          0
1      a          0
2      b          1
3      b          1
4      a          2
5      c          3
```

How can I use ngroup() to get my desired output? If ngroup() isn't able to do this, how can I solve this? (Preferably without loops)

Thank you!

Comment: `df.letter.ne(df.letter.shift()).cumsum()`

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you!